# Joining attribute table with excel file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, excel

I am using qgis version 2.18.19.I want to join excel file with the attribute table of a shape file.My attribute table has 1 row and 4 column.Excel file table has 1 column and 8 rows.I have experience in joining excel file which include 8 column and 1 row.

Therefore I feel,If i can convert excel table of 8 rows 1 column in to a table of 8 column and 1 row withing the qgis,There is a chance to achieve my goal.So is this possible in qgis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  a previous post [Transpose attribute table in QGIS Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226939/transpose-attribute-table-in-qgis-composer), this can't be done inside QGIS, but there is a good work around:

- Save your table as a CSV file,Right-click the file and go to save as
- in format choose Comma Separated Values (CSV)
- open it in Excel.
- use copy, [Paste Special ->Transpose](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744), in excel after (or before) you've filtered your data.

the first link provides some Pictures if you struggled...

Comment: Actually I am new to this site.Some time my question may be very primary question.But your answer really helpful.It helps me to think differently.thank you very much