# Rotate a table but not the text in a QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, table, layouts, text

I'm working in a QGIS Layout and I have an special requirement: I have to rotate a table but I need that the text remains horizontal. When I check the rotation  settings, the "Expression" option just let me to make an expression for changing the orientation of the table but not the text.

Is there any way to solve this tricky problem?

[image: I need the records and field texts in horizontal but the fields and record boxes set vertical]

Comment: Currently, transpose a table is not supported, but you can achieve it with a workaround using the answer in this question [Transpose attribute table in QGIS Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226956/63384)

Comment: I would add that in 3.14 (and of course the current dev version), you will be able to [paste tabular data directly into a fixed table](https://pigreco.github.io/changelog314/#add-import-content-from-clipboard-for-fixed-table-items) which can save a couple of steps.